# Chat does not resize correctly

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, design, chat

It's not the end of the world, but even so I will occasionally decrease the size of chat window so that I can do other things while keeping an eye on it.

*If I make the window too small I get this:*

[image]

There are a number of problems:

- Tags, users present, name and description of room overlap the messages.
- The room name completely overflows page even after scrolling.
- `send` and `upload` cannot be pressed even after scrolling.
- The other rooms present disappear completely.
- Starred messages are unavailable.

*Perhaps the window is too small so I resized to exactly half screen:*

[image]

Even here the problem does not fix.

- The `upload` and `send` buttons still overflow.
- It is impossible to see which other rooms I am in and the starred messages if the room description is too long.
- `all rooms` and search bar do not align.

Here are a few suggestions that may help improve user experience:

- Prevent the tags, users present, name and description of room overlap the messages.
- Allow `send` and `upload` to be always accessible.
- When the window is small: resize messages so that a lot of scrolling right and left is not necessary.  Hide some of the users, allow 5-10 of the currently active users to be displayed and a tab marked "See all users" that expands to show all present and add a scrollbar or drop-down of room description.

Many sites can be comfortably resized, unlike the chat where resizing is awkward.  Could something be done to make the Stack Overflow chat more window resizing friendly?

Also why has this not been done already and are there plans to improve the usability when in small screen in the future?

Comment: "Also why has this not been done already and are there plans to improve the usability when in small screen in the future?" Probably because the CEO has said he thinks chat is stupid and so not many resources are spent on supporting it or improving it. It's always been an awkward 3rd space, at best.

Comment: @TylerH  So all us 3rd space users suffer, that is just so sad.  :(

Comment: @TylerH -  Is that a fact?  *`The CEO has said he thinks chat is stupid`?*

Comment: @ashleedawg Yes he said it on a Stack Exchange podcast a couple years ago.